# Linked List Priority Queue with addition conditions

Tags: c++

I have tired coding the normal priority. Now i would want to add in 1 or 2 more conditions into my code.

Here's my current normal priority code:

```
void queue::addToQueueList(int newPriority, double newFare, int custID)
{
    node* newnode= new node;
    newnode->priority= newPriority;
    newnode->fare = newFare;
    newnode->cusID = custID;
    newnode->next= NULL;

    if (front == NULL || newnode->priority < front->priority)
    {

                newnode->next = front;

                front = newnode;

    }
    else
    {

                node* q = front;
        node* p;
                while (q->next != NULL && q->next->priority <= newnode->priority)
        {   

            q=q->next;
        }


            newnode->next = q->next;
            q->next = newnode;



    }
}
```

how can i add in addition condition example if found priority same, compare the fare. the  highest of the fare will be priority.

Thanks

Comment: Two steps: Firstly, extract a single function `bool compare(node const& n1, node const& n2)` from the existing code, it should return whether `n1` should come before `n2`. Then, extend that function to take the fare into account when two elements have the same priority, which I believe is what you want. Also, you should have a set of tests that make sure that the thing behaves as expected. I'm not giving any further hints, because this looks suspiciously like homework, but using this info plus some effort on your own you should be able to solve this.

Comment: Please format and indent your code.

Comment: Hi Ulrich Eckhardt, THank you .. =)

Comment: to "Lightness Races in Orbit": I believe everyone is here to help each other to learn. so I hope you can give more constructive comments rather like giving an unclear feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood you need the following

```
#include <utility>

//...

void queue::addToQueueList(int newPriority, double newFare, int custID)
{
    node* newnode= new node;
    newnode->priority= newPriority;
    newnode->fare = newFare;
    newnode->cusID = custID;
    newnode->next= NULL;

    auto p = std::make_pair( newPriority, newFare );

    if (front == NULL || p < std::make_pair( front->priority, front->fare ) )
    {

                newnode->next = front;

                front = newnode;

    }
    else
    {

                node* q = front;
                while (q->next != NULL && 
                       std::make_pair( q->next->priority, q->next->fare ) <= p)
        {   

            q=q->next;
        }


            newnode->next = q->next;
            q->next = newnode;



    }
}
```

Also it seems that statement

```
        node* p;
```

may be removed from the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did:

```
void queue::addToQueueList(int newPriority, double newFare, int custID)
{
    node* newnode= new node;
    newnode->priority= newPriority;
    newnode->fare = newFare;
    newnode->cusID = custID;
    newnode->next= NULL;

    if (front == NULL || newnode->priority < front->priority)
    {

                newnode->next = front;

                front = newnode;

    }
    else
    {

                node* q = front;
        node* p;
                while (q->next != NULL && q->next->priority <= newnode->priority)
        {   
            p=q;
            q=q->next;
        }

            bool chk = compare(q,newnode);
        if(chk)
        {
            p->next = newnode;
            newnode->next = q;

        }
        else
        {
            newnode->next = q->next;
            q->next = newnode;
        }       


    }
}
bool queue::compare(node* const& n1, node* const& n2)
{
    bool check = false;
    if(n1->priority == n2->priority)
    {
        if(n2->fare > n1->fare)
        {
            check = true;
        }
    }
    return check;
}
```